# How To Get ACF Field in Custom Post Type Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, advanced-custom-fields

I created a custom post type for 'projects'. I also created custom field for the post type 'projects', however i cant seem to access them, not sure what im doing wrong. Here's my code:

```
<?php 
  $args = array (
  'post_type' => 'project',
  'status' => 'publish',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'posts_per_page' => -1
  );
 $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>

 <div class="home-slider">

  <?php if($the_query->have_posts()) : ?>
   <?php while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="slide">

      <div class="project-name">
       <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
      </div>

      <div class="project-description">
       <?php echo get_field('intro_text'); ?>
      </div>

     </div>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
 <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. Can you please share screenshots of acf field group where you have set this up and a project post where the fields and data can be seen.

Answer (score 1):

If your post type is called 'projects' maybe this is the issue

```
'post_type' => 'project(s)',
```